# Run function several times VBA

Tags: excel, vba, call

I want to call a function several time (with differents values) when I click on a button.
But when I click on it, the function run 1 time (for chart 7 in the example) and then stop. The function don't continue (for chart 3 in the example). Any idea why?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
    Call changechart(Range("F2:G11"), "Title 1")

    Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    Call changechart(Range("A11:B18"), "Title 2")
End Sub
```

```
Sub changechart(x As Range, T As String)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = T
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet2").x
End Sub
```

I tried to put all functions in a master function instead of in the commandbutton1_click: same result.

Comment: The error encountered as you called _Activate_ chart object before calling _changechart_ function. You can directly reference the chart without activating at the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Change Chart

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ChangeChart .ChartObjects("Chart 7"), "F2:G11", "Title 1"
        ChangeChart .ChartObjects("Chart 3"), "A11:B18", "Title 2"
    End With
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub ChangeChart( _
        ByVal cho As ChartObject, _
        ByVal RangeAddress As String, _
        ByVal Title As String)
    With cho.Chart
        .ChartTitle.Text = Title
        .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(RangeAddress)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Sheets("Sheet2").x` doesn't work.
- Your code only changes `ChartTitle` of `chart 7`, then `SetSourceData` raises error.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Changechart("Chart 7", "F2:G11", "Title 1")
    Call Changechart("Chart 3", "A11:B18", "Title 2")
End Sub
Sub Changechart(ByVal sCht As String, ByVal sSrc As String, ByVal T As String)
    With Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(sCht)
        .ChartTitle.Text = T
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(sSrc)
    End With
End Sub
```